# Heroku and python files

Tags: python, heroku, file-storage

I know that Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem and clears files directories on server restart. But here is an issue: i want be able to save and open file after a few seconds, but heroku does'nt allow me to make it and it doesn't creates any files in given folder (note, the folder exists).

Do you have any suggestions?

Here is how i try to save the file in system storage.

File_path is for example media/data_sets/test.csv

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(csv_header + '\n')
        for i in range(self.rows):
            line = next(generator)
            if i != self.rows - 1:
                line += '\n'
            file.write(line)
```

Comment: "but heroku does'nt allow me to make it and it doesn't creates any files in given folder"—please show us the relevant code. See [ask].

Comment: I'm sory, here it is, just simple file open with python.

Comment: If you aren't getting an error message this is probably working, you just don't know where the file is going.  `media/data_sets/test.csv` is relative to whatever the working directory is. I suggest you use an absolute path, or something relative to a known location.

Comment: Either that, or you are trying to access it from another dyno (e.g. a one-off dyno) where it won't exist. How are you trying to read / access the file later?

Comment: I try to use it in the same dino. Actually it's a Django project and this way i make custom file creating. The full path of file on my local PC is F:\ProjectName\media\data_sets\test.csv
In dyno console i tried to look for any files with .csv, but i didn't found it, so it seems that heroku doesn't allow me to even create the file

Comment: What do you mean by "In dyno console"? If you're doing `heroku run bash` or similar, that gives you a new one-off dyno. It is _not_ the same as the one where your app is running.

Comment: Oh, i thought it's the same

Comment: [It is not](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno)

Comment: Wait, can it be the problem because of creating file in Celery and trying to read in Django (this are separate dynos)

Comment: Yes, very likely. Not only does Heroku provide an ephemeral filesystem, but each dyno gets its _own_ filesystem. Think of dynos as completely isolated mini VMs. I suggest you transfer this data some other way, e.g. by putting the files on Amazon S3 / Azure Blob Storage / etc. or storing it in a data layer.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that every dynamic has its own file system. To use the common system we need to start celery with django on one dyno using (&)

Comment: "To use the common system we need to start celery with django on one dyno using (&)"—that's an antipattern that I wouldn't recommend. Heroku's architecture is very carefully designed. Fighting against it isn't a good indicator.